# How can I build the documentation for the EPPlus library?

Tags: epplus

I just downloaded the EPPlus library from GitHub.  That's a library for working with Excel files in C#.  The only documentation provided is a Sandcastle Help File Builder project (EPPlusDoc.shfbproj).  I downloaded Sandcastle, opened the project in Visual Studio 2017 and ran it.  I got an error message saying "BUILD FAILED: You must specify at least one documentation source in the form of an assembly or a Visual Studio solution/project file.  The project shows two documentation sources: EPPlus.dll and EPPlus.xml.  What do I have to do to build the documentation for this library?

(And why the heck didn't the developer just provide a simple .chm file instead of making me go through this exercise myself?

Comment: Why do you try to build the project instead of using [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)? The documentation is in the Github repo's [Wiki](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki), not the sandcastle project

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the NuGet package.  I did not know it existed.  I only stumbled across a reference to EPPlus by accident, and that reference was to the GitHub repository.  Also, I am significantly behind the times, and I don't really know how to use NuGet or GitHub.